# chrome mistakenly show my older app name when try to add my app to the chrome apps in my browser

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

Using the Customize and control Google Chrome menu when try to add my react app to my google apps I see the name of an older app appears in the menu and dont see the new app name as appears in the new app manifest I've build and served